# How to stop sharingd, unsolicited, acceptance window from spawning and disappearing instantly every time the computer starts?

Tags: remote-desktop, services, launch-services

I have been living with this for a long time, but now (hope with your help) I am committed to solve it because it doesn't look quite normal.

Why this window of this `sharingd` process, shows up at boot time in desktop almost in milliseconds and disappears (like if it was granted with some kind of "auto click"). I don't share (wish not) anything with any other host in any net. This is a plain standalone home computer with its plain vanilla internet connection.

Likely targets:

```
com.apple.sharingd (signer: Apple Proper) 
com.apple.preferences.sharing.remoteservice (signer: Apple Proper)
```

In my share settings I have all unticked (no file sharing, no remote services, nothing).

And, why shows this behaviour if many other services start as well, but they don't throw "grant/acceptance windows" on desktop?

If is a system necessary process I just don't want to remove it from disk (i. e. deleting the `com.apple.sharingd...`), but should be a way to disable it?
I also don't want just to block it through firewall. I would like to do it the good way. Stopping the service, yes?

Any command line string to stop it?

Thank you.

Comment: sharingd is part of the OS, and it is entirely normal for it to launch, even if it's just confirming that there's nothing to share with, like a phone, another computer, or NAS on the local network.

Comment: @benwiggy So you mean also the "spawning"-disappearing behavior on desktop at startup is normal as well? (why not happening on background/invisible as all the rest of the services? Above all, is almost impossible interacting with that flashing-one-time window). Thx.

Comment: What, and where, do you see?

Comment: @benwiggy Boot > Login > Desktop (HERE). Right after logging, when Desktop shows up, a typical query window asking: "Do you want the application “sharingd” to accept incoming network connections?". I could grab the message doing screenshots sometime when the boot was a bit slow. That query box has two options, accept or refuse. I never interacted (at most I remember I could have click in refuse being luck in those slow computer days, but still continues showing). It just disappears and system has been functioning without problem from this... Also, no "sharingd" entry in the firewall.

Comment: Have you got Little Snitch or similar installed?

Comment: @benwiggy no. Just the native plain vanilla MacOS firewall. Actually the query is the typical one from our well familiar firewall that asks for any application it firsts asks for incoming connections.

Comment: @benwiggy from system log reviewed now (I am going to remove the: /Users/user/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sharingd.plist). system.log: "Jul 16 09:19:57 user com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sharingd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient" (6 message entries. Jul16/17, 2020).